# Obtener archivos .m3u descargados con wget en un sólo fichero

Tags: bash, wget

Cuando abro vlc en mi pc, veo icecast radio stations, pero en mi movil no. Asi que intento bajar/registrar todos los `.m3u` de `http://dir.xiph.org/` y dejarlos en un fichero .m3u para poder abrirlo con vlc de movil o cuando necesite. Si hago:

```
wget \
    -P /tmp/icecast/ \
    --referer=http://dir.xiph.org/ \
    --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux amd64; rv:32.0b4) Gecko/20140804164216 ArchLinux KDE Firefox/32.0b4" \
    -rpkc \
    -l 0 \
    -m "http://dir.xiph.org/" \
    -R "index.html*" \
    -e robots=off
```

descarga toda la página completa incluidos todos.m3u. Después intenté:

```
wget \
    -P /tmp/icecast/ \
    --referer=http://dir.xiph.org/ \
    --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux amd64; rv:32.0b4) Gecko/20140804164216 ArchLinux KDE Firefox/32.0b4" \
    -rpkc \
    -l 0 \
    -m "http://dir.xiph.org/" \
    -A .m3u \
    -R "index.html*" \
    -e robots=off
```

Solo descarga algunos .m3u en cada ejecución. ¿Cómo podría hacer para tener todos los .m3u en un sólo fichero, a ser posible con los titulos de cada canal?

Answer (score 0):

Para copiar o mover los archivos a una carpeta, podrías usar

```
mkdir /tmp/songs
find /tmp/icecast/dir.xiph.org/ -name "*.m3u" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cp {} /tmp/songs/"$(cut -d / -f 6- <<< {} | tr / _)"'
```

Y, por ejemplo, un archivo `listen.m3u` en la carpeta `2825990` lo mueve a la carpeta `/tmp/songs` con el nombre de `2825990_listen.m3u`.

Para la pregunta de los títulos de cada canal, es un poco más laborioso. Tendrías que revisar en la página descargada, en algún archivo, por ejemplo, parece ser que están en xml, el nombre del canal y procesar ese archivo para obtener el nombre del canal, la ruta y nombre de la canción a la que hace referencia.